# How to use State Variable (useState) in an EventHandler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an React Functional Component which recieves a prop with a variable from useState(). This works fine but if I use it in an EventListener it does not get updated. I tried the following but still it does not work.

Maybe someone can explain why.

Thanks

I would expect x to be the updated number but it always has the value of the initial setup of the EventHandler.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
   const [num, setNum] = useState(50);

  return (
    <div>
       <button onClick={() => setNum(prev => prev + 1)}>Test</button>
       <div>{num}</div>
       <Child num={num} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ num }) => {
  let x = 0;
  const md = () => {
  console.log(num, x);
};

useEffect(() => {
x = num;
  }, [num]);

useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("mousedown", md);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", md);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div id="box">click {num}</div>; 
};

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each render of your `Child` will get a new `x`, a new `props` object, etc.  However you are binding your event listener only once and so capturing only the initial `props.num` value.

Two ways to fix:

Rebind event listener when `num` changes, by passing `num` as a dependency to your effect to bind the event listener:

```
const Child = ({ num }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    // no need to define this in main function since it is only
    // used inside this effect
    const md = () => { console.log(num); };
    document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("mousedown", md);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", md);
    };
  }, [num]);

  return <div id="box">click {num}</div>; 
};
```

Or use a `ref` to hold the value of num and bind your event listener to the ref.  This gives you a level of indirection to handle the change:

```
const Child = ({ num }) => {
  const numRef = useRef();  // will be same object each render
  numRef.current = num; // assign new num value each render

  useEffect(() => {
    // no need to define this in main function since it is only
    // used inside this effect
    // binds to same ref object, and reaches in to get current num value
    const md = () => { console.log(numRef.current); };
    document.getElementById("box").addEventListener("mousedown", md);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", md);
    };
  }, []);

  return <div id="box">click {num}</div>; 
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. If I use option 1 wouldn't I be creating alot of unnecessary EventListeners and flood memory? Version 2 seems better. My workaround was to use a hidden html input field with the value of the num state. But this is ugly ofcourse.

Comment: Version one removes the old event listener each time it adds a new one (because your effect returns a function to remove the listener). It is ok for low frequency changes, like the ones triggered from a button clock. The pattern in Option 2 is better for high frequency changes and is more versatile in general. It’s probably the one I’d use